# Styling chapter number in chapter heading - MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

How create a numbered Heading 1 that looks like this in MS Word?

[image: fancy chapter heading]

I need it to appeary correctly in TOC:

1  First chapter title

2  Second chapter title

3  Heading on level 0

Comment: Your question is way too vague. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several requirements to do this and the first is a thorough understanding of multilevel lists. The resource to use for that is the late Shauna Kelly's website, which is still maintained by a group of dedicated Microsoft MVP volunteers. The specific article to read is "[How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word…](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)" The article discusses Word 2007 and 2010, and it still applies for Word 2013, 2016 (PC or Mac). If you'd rather not use the direct link, then do a web search on **ShaunaKelly.com** and navigate to the article from there.

If you read the article and practice making a multilevel list, here are a few other special requirements to make, the Heading 1 style to look as you have specified.

1. The Heading 1 style will require an additional `Points Before` setting
   on this paragraph so that it inserts automatically half way down the
   page. (**Paragraph Formatting Dialog**)
2. The Heading 1 style should be set to `Right Aligned`. (**Paragraph Formatting Dialog**)
3. The Heading 1 style should include the `Page Break Before` property. (**Paragraph Formatting Dialog**)
4. After inserting a new Heading 1 styled text for the chapter, you will manually insert a line feed character (`Shift + Return`) between the Chapter Number and the Chapter Name. The line feed character will not appear in the TOC.
5. If you are using the Heading 1 content in a `StyleRef` field so the data value can be populated into other parts of the document, apply a `Hidden` font attribute on the inserted **Line Feed** character. (**Format Font Dialog**)
6. When making the custom settings for Heading 1 in the Define New Multilevel List dialog, use the `Font` button on the dialog to set the expanded size of the Chapter Number for Heading 1 only. All other list levels should remain the default size for the paragraph.

I can't stress enough that mastering the creation of multilevel lists is essential if you are going to make this work consistently throughout your document.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have managed to get the desired look by following your instructions.   Now I have one more problem. I have a chapter title placed in page header with code {STYLEREF  "Heading 1" }, but it is picking up the manual linebreaks (Shift+Return), so header gets expanded to multiple lines and text is partlially cut off. Is there a way to make it ignore linebreaks in page header?

Comment: @anchi, I've added an additional item to my answer that will handle your StyleRef issue. Since my instructions work for you, hopefully you will upvote and mark my response as answering you question. :-)